# Unable to integrate Cleanse in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, square, cleanse

I am developing my first `iOS` app and I am trying to integrate [Cleanse](https://github.com/square/Cleanse) into my project.
I dragged `Cleanse.xcodeproj` and dropped into an workspace in Xcode.
I also added `Cleanse.framework` as a target dependency and embedded it. 
However, I get the following error :

```
Build Target Cleanse
Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
```

*PS : I am using Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)*

Comment: What is your build error? We can't help you if we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow those directions? It appears Cleanse wasn't built using Swift 3, it needs to be updated to the latest syntax. Follow those directions, select the framework, and choose Swift 3. That should be all you need.

If you need any further clarification just let me know. Hope this helps.